# What are the differences between "$n$-th level e-bits" and "$n$-th level qunits"?

Tags: entanglement, quantum-state

I have seen qubits, qutrits & entangled bits (e-bits) a decent amount. I have also seen qunits/qudits for n-th level qubits. What I am trying to wrap my head around is the differences between n-th level e-bits vs n-th level qunits. What are the similarities? Differences?

**What generalizations exist about n-th level e-bits / qunits?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>**Disclaimer**: Since you haven't stated the source from where you got those terms, I will mention the most *obvious* definitions for those, which occur *to me* - simply looking at the names.</sup>

"**Qunit**" refers to any quantum system whose state lies in a complex [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) whose [dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(vector_space)) is *any* natural number $n$. Example of qunits are qubits, for which $n=2$ and qutrits for which $n=3$. Also check this for other less commonly used terms: [Do any specific types of qudits other than qubits and qutrits have a name?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/do-any-specific-types-of-qudits-other-than-qubits-and-qutrits-have-a-name/2102)

Next, remember that a system of two qu**bits** will lie in a $2\times 2$-dimensional vector space i.e. $\Bbb C^2\times \Bbb C^2$. A system of three qubits will lie in a $2\times 2 \times 2$-dimensional vector space $\Bbb C^2\times \Bbb C^2\times \Bbb C^2$ and so on. By "$n$-dimensional" e-**bits** they're referring to the dimension of the vector space again. As for the "e-**bit**" part, that's simple. That is, the state of the system of qubits is basically not separable into individual qubit states lying in $\Bbb C^2$ each (i.e. the qubits are *entangled*). Check out the answers in: [How do I show that a two-qubit state is an entangled state?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/how-do-i-show-that-a-two-qubit-state-is-an-entangled-state)